# Combinations of 2 lists

Tags: python, list, combinations

```
Input: [1, 2, 3] [a, b]

Expected Output: [(1,a),(1,b),(2,a),(2,b),(3,a),(3,b)]
```

This works, but is there a better way without an if statement?

```
[(x,y) for (x,y) in list(combinations(chain(a,b), 2)) if x in a and y in b]
```

Comment: `[(x,y) for x in a for y in b]`?

Comment: You can use [itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product): `list(x for x in itertools.product([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b']))`

Comment: @jszakmeister Or just `list(itertools.product([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b']))`, ;)

Comment: Thanks Wondercricket, that's what I was looking for. @schwobaseggl does product work for n lists? Like (a,b,c) for [a][b][c], (a,b,c,d) for [a][b][c][d], etc?

Comment: @schwobaseggl haha, yes!  I have no idea what I was thinking. :-)

Comment: Sigh.  I don't think the referenced question is actually similar enough to this one. :-(  `zip()` is the wrong solution here and `map()` isn't necessarily a better solution either.

Answer (score 38):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), your handy library tool  for a cartesian product:

```
from itertools import product

l1, l2 = [1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b']
output = list(product(l1, l2))
# [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'a'), (3, 'b')]
```