# List Comprehension: Nested loop with append statement

Tags: python, loops, nested, list-comprehension

I have this piece of python code

```
xy_tups = []
for x in ['m', 't', 'b']:
    for y in ['b', 't', 'e']:
        if x != y:
            xy_tups.append ((x, y))
```

that outputs this: `[('m', 'b'), ('m', 't'), ('m', 'e'), ('t', 'b'), ('t', 'e'), ('b', 't'), ('b', 'e')]`

I need to create a list comprehension version of this piece of code but I am having trouble figuring it out. I have tried these methods

```
 xy_tups = [x for x in ['m', 't', 'b'] and y for y in ['b', 't', 'e'] if x != y] 

 xy_tups = [x for y in ['m', 't', 'b'] and y for x in ['b', 't', 'e'] if x != y]
```

and I have tried adding the `xy_tups.append(x,y)` to the list comprehension code but I get errors. I understand that each letter in the `x` list is joined with each letter of the `y` list once, but I cannot figure out how to put together the list comprehension.

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) have an example, nearly exactly like your question.

Comment: Here's an alternate approach of you're not limited to using list comprehension. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918272/combinations-of-2-lists

Answer (score 1):

```
xy_tups = [(x,y) for x in ['m , 't', 'b'] for y in ['b', 't', 'e'] if x != y ]
print(xy_tups)
```

**Output:**
[('m', 'b'), ('m', 't'), ('m', 'e'), ('t', 'b'), ('t', 'e'), ('b', 't'), ('b', 'e')]

Answer (score 0):

```
[(a, b) for a in ['m', 't', 'b'] for b in ['b', 't', 'e'] if a != b]
```

outputs

```
[('m', 'b'), ('m', 't'), ('m', 'e'), ('t', 'b'), ('t', 'e'), ('b', 't'), ('b','e')]
```