# Keyword combiner tool

Tags: python

I want to challenge myself and I want to build a keyword combiner tool like these ones:

- https://adresults.com/tools/keyword-combiner-tool/
- https://kombinator.org/

I would like to build this using Python but I don't really know how to combine the items from a list with another list:

```
a = ['blue', 'red', 'green']
b = ['shoes', 'shirt', 'pants']

c = a + b
```

And if I print `c` I get this:

```
['blue', 'red', 'green', 'shoes', 'shirt', 'pants']
```

But I want it to be combined as this:

```
 - blue shoes
 - red shoes 
 - green shoes
```

Comment: See "itertools.product"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Comment: Sorry, correct dupe: [Combinations of 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918272/combinations-of-2-lists)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get a list containing all the possible combinations, this might be the fastest way

```
c = [(x+" "+y) for x in a for y in b]
```

It iterates through both list and writes all combinations in the new list.

In the end: `c = ['blue shoes', 'blue shirt', 'blue pants', 'red shoes', 'red shirt', 'red pants', 'green shoes', 'green shirt', 'green pants']`

Comment: I didn't downvote (this is correct...), but this is basically what [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) does...

Comment: I understand, but it might be better not to import a custom module just for this one thing that can be done in a single line otherwise...

Comment: `itertools` is a built-in library... Again, I didn't downvote and your answer is perfectly fine and correct...